# Most desired feature of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, ide

What do you think will be most desired feature of eclipse which does not exist yet?

Comment: Nothing, perfect the way it is.

Comment: @Stephen You should switch to Emacs then :D.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to integrate **IM**(AIM, MSN...) in Eclipse.

Although I found some IM-plugins, they don't work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really have a need for this, but many people want some way to create user-defined folding regions.  Of course, this can lead to bad code, but other IDEs have it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd think good and easy maven support, btw netbeans as very good maven support

Answer (score 2):

I would love elaborate search/replace feature like Labwindows/CVI and PSPad editor that can take folder selection input.

Comment: NOTE: Currently, Eclipse only allows search/replace on the resource coming from a defined working set.

Answer (score 2):

Read my mind and spit out code on the editor!

j/k.

1. I think Eclipse needs a better UI toolbox.
2. While you can refactor code to some extent, wouldn't it be awesome if it could also suggest design patterns for any recognizable patterns?

Answer (score 2):

Scripting support.

There has been several attempts, but none of them really succeeded.  There should be a standard which all Eclipse projects align to.